# Spawning an ephemeral OverlayEntry based on a StateProvider update

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

**TL;DR:** I want to spawn a temporary overlay whenever there's a state change, and I don't really know how to approach it. (I'm using riverpod)

I have an OverlayEntry widget that I want to spawn whenever there's a state change in a StateProvider (I'm not married to anything, it doesn't have to be a StateProvider and this doesn't have to be a widget)

I tried messing around with ChangeNotifier and StateNotifier but to no avail. I'm having a tough time understanding them and I couldn't find any example of stuff that is similar to what I'm looking.

My current approach is to create a widget which is a builder for the main page, the widget for the main page should have a listener for the StateProvider and will build the main page widget. Whenever the listener is called, I want to spawn that overlay (by calling a method?)

But I can't seem to figure it out. This is my current code refs and ideas. this ***does not*** work.

**CustomOverlay widget:**

```dart
class CustomOverlay extends HookWidget {
  final bool currentState;
    
  PlayerOverlay({this.currentState});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = useAnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500);
    Animation<double> _fadeInFadeOut = createCurvedAnimation(controller);
    controller.addStatusListener((status) => loopAnimation(status, controller));
    return createFadeTransition(context, _fadeInFadeOut);
  }

  ...

}
```

**MainPageBuilder**

```dart
class PlayerPageBuilder extends HookWidget {
  final CustomOverlay playerOverlay;
  final MainPage playerPage;

  MainPageBuilder(this.customOverlay, this.mainPage);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentState = useProvider
    currentStateProvider.addListener(() { // obviously this doesnt exist, and I'm having a tough time figuring it out (how to use StateNotifierProvider or anything that fits)
        spawnOverlayAnimation(context, customOverlay);
    });
    return mainPage;
  }

  spawnPlayerOverlayAnimation(BuildContext context, Widget child) async {
    OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        child: child,
      ),
    );
    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    overlayEntry.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: check how `Tooltip` removes a temporary overlay here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ce40de69b7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tooltip.dart#L324

Comment: @pskink that's an interesting idea, but the thing is that i dont want to tie the invokation of the overlayentry to a gesturedetector, i want to tie it to a change in stateprovider/statenotifierprovider/notifierprovider

Comment: @pskink my problem is not showing or hiding the overlay, i've already accomplished that. i want it to proc based on a state change, and not on something explicit like a gesturedetector

Comment: and if you played with `ChangeNotifier` then you probably used a concrete implementation:  `ValueNotifier`, right? if so, tried to use `ValueListenableBuilder` which rebuilds every time `ValueNotifier` changes?

Comment: I did, but didn't manage to make it work. It's important for it to listen to a provider's state because it's not the only thing that is supposed to be updated. i want to create something like a pubsub mechanism in which when there's a change in the value, multiple stuff get updated as a result of that change (be it widgets AND random dart code)

Comment: `child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
valueListenable: vl,
builder: (ctx, value, child) {
var entry = OverlayEntry(
builder: (ctx) => Container(color: Colors.black54)
);
Future(() => Overlay.of(ctx).insert(entry));
Future.delayed(3.seconds, () => entry.remove());
return Text('foooo $value', textScaleFactor: 3);
},
),` here `vl` is `ValueNotifier<int>` - you can change it in some button callback by: `vl.value++;` which changes its value and rebuilds `ValueListenableBuilder`

Comment: Have you tried with ProviderListener? https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/all/ProviderListener-class.html you can use the onChange to open dialogs or in your case, show the overlay (you said you already had that logic)